# how do I center a 615 pixel image inside a table-cell of a 750 pixel box?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel that might have images that are not the full height or width, plus the height is dynamic for each carousel. I managed to get them vertically into the middle, but horizontally I can't seem to center it. Is there any way to achieve this?

The code is like:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="height: 925px;">

    <div class="carousel-inside">
    <div class="item active" data-slide-number="1">

    <span class="to-middle" style="height: 925px;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/615x375" class="img-responsive img-big" 
        style="max-height: 925px;">
    </span>

    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

A working version is at http://jsfiddle.net/ka7z7z55/

Thank you for any advice or hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, add `display:table` and `width:100%` to the `.item`.

```
.carousel-inside>.item {
    position: relative;
    /*  Changes */
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/ka7z7z55/2/)

Comment: @user2642641 Does it fix your problem?

Comment: It did indeed! Thank you so much. You saved my day :)